# Automatic Point detection and Homography of a football field

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, homography

So I am working on a computer vision project of automatic point detection on picture of a football field and then perform homography.
The idea is to choose 4 points in clockwise/anticlockwise in the football picture taken from a game and match it with points on a standard diagram of a football field.

So the image that I used was:
[The Original Image The I am Working On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW11I.jpg)

The standard Football pitch diagram that i used:
[The Football Field Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwb9a.png)

Step1: I did processing to segment the image and remove the non-field parts
and result is : [Preprocessed snaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYJdI.jpg)

Step2: then I found 4 points by finding the intersection points of lines in the picture and choosing two vertical lines whose point I used to get this: [Output Of Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHcfy.jpg)

code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random
import math

def find_intersections(lines):
    intersections = []
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lines)):
            line1 = lines[i]
            line2 = lines[j]
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = line1[0]
            x3, y3, x4, y4 = line2[0]
            denominator = (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4)
            if denominator != 0:
                x = ((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (x3 - x4) - (x1 - x2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)) / denominator
                y = ((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)) / denominator
                intersections.append((int(x), int(y)))
    return intersections

def main():
    # Load the football field image
    image = cv2.imread(r'Preprosessed Snaps\\Segmented1.jpg')

    #Canny
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

    # Apply Hough line transformation to detect lines
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 100, None, 50, 20)

    # Find intersection points
    intersections = find_intersections(lines)

    # Draw lines and intersection points on the image
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

    ori_points = []
    k = 1
    
    for line in lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
        angle = np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / np.pi
        if k<=2:
            if abs(angle) < 15:
                # Horizontal line
                cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)
                if(k%2!=0):
                    ori_points.append((int(x1),int(y1)))
                    ori_points.append((int(x2),int(y2)))
                    k=k+1
                else:
                    ori_points.append((int(x2),int(y2)))
                    ori_points.append((int(x1),int(y1)))
                    k=k+1
            
    for point in intersections:
        cv2.circle(image, point, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    # Display the image with lines and intersection points
    cv2.imshow('Football Field', image)
    cv2.imwrite(r'OutputStep2\\OutputBH1.jpg',image)
    print(ori_points)
    
    #Saving Line Co-ordinates
    with open(r'OutputCoordinate\\outputco1.txt', 'w') as file:
        # Step 2: Convert the list elements to strings
        str_list = [str(element) for element in ori_points]
        
        # Step 3: Join the list elements into a single string
        list_string = '\n'.join(str_list)  # Separate elements by a new line
        
        # Step 4: Write the string to the file
        file.write(list_string)
    
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Step3: Then I performed the homography by manually choosing the destination points by looking at both the picture (output of step 2) and football field field diagram to find the destination points in the picture of field diagram that matches the four points we got in step 2 so the result came out like this:
[Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjui0.jpg)
Code:

```
#Main Homography

import cv2
import numpy as np

source = cv2.imread(r'Original Snaps\\Example1.png')
source = cv2.resize(source, (640, 480))
cv2.imshow("Source Image", source)
pts_src = np.array([[6,249],[282,312],[638,124], [425,98]])


destination = cv2.imread(r'FieldDiagram.png')
cv2.imshow("Destination Image", destination)
pts_dst = np.array([[12,397],[125, 397],[125,125],[12,135]])

h,status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)
im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(source, h, (destination.shape[1],destination.shape[0]))
cv2.imshow("Warped Source Image", im_out)
cv2.imwrite(r'Output snaps without D\\outputD1.jpg',im_out)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Now the result : [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzolX.jpg)

that I got is ok I am satisfied with it but in step 3 the 4 points from this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoOIV.png) that i chose manually I want find those 4 points automatically.